# How to get list of currently running applications /installed applications list?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Is there any possible to get list of currently running applications (like task manager processes) in windows 8 system or to get list of installed applications list in windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

Nope Metro apps as sandboxed and can only talk to other apps through Contracts.. Querying for other apps isn't something that is beneficial to the apps in general and isn't supported

Comment: then how can we can we get recently used files  for all applications like [in windows 7 recent files are showing in start menu].

Comment: actually i want to create  a list for recently used files for all applications or for running applications for windows store app

Comment: This is not possible. I think you will have to think of something else